# Magento 1.9.1.0 Cron job / Order confirmation mail not sent

Tags: email, cron, order-email

I've set up a Cron job through cPanel for my Magento install using the code:

`* * * * * wget -O /dev/null -q http://www.webpage.com/shop/cron.php > /dev/null`

(the `cron.php` file is in the `public_html/shop/` folder).

The Cron settings in the Admin panel are:

[image: Cron settings]

I installed SMTP pro, and the Self-Test was successful.

I installed AOL Scheduler and the timeline looks like this:

[image: AOL Scheduler timeline]

But order confirmation mails are still not send to the customers.

Anyone has an idea what could be the problem?

Regards

Comment: Are you sure the mail() PHP function works? It sees everything else is in place.

Comment: From what I've tried, every other mail (invoice info, shipping info etc.) is sent without any problem. The problem is only with order confirmation. So I guess the mail() function is OK. If you need any code to check it I'll provide it.

Comment: I had this issue in the past and solved it resaving the cron settings in the admin (just save it without any change) and also truncating the mail queue table in the db (I don't remember the name but it has queue in it)

Comment: And how about this? :)
[image](http://prntscr.com/7pkma5)

Comment: Don't use `wget` for cron execution. Go to `System > Scheduler > Instructions` to see how to set up the optimal crontab for Aoe_Scheduler

Comment: I can't find System > Scheduler > Instructions. And what should be used instead of wget? If you know a solution please write a complete answer.